# Star symbol too small in a dialer-like view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I'm trying to create a dialer-like application:

[image: My dialer]

I'm using `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:33]`. The problem is that the Asterisk symbol is too small in comparison to the numbers and '#'.

I printed 123*# in all 61 available iOS6 fonts and the star is smaller than other chars in all of them.

Does somebody have an idea how to solve this?

One thing I tried is changing font size only for * button. That works, but when I hit this button it appears small [off course] in the input above...

Hope my Question is clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a different character for the display. In Xcode, click on the Edit menu and select Special Characters. When the character viewer appears, type "asterisk" into the search field. Try one of the many other related symbols.

Depending on how you do this, you may need to replace the used symbol with a proper asterisk internally to use the result in a `tel` URL.

Comment: Specifically, try `U+FF0A FULLWIDTH ASTERISK`. (But as @rmaddy notes you'll only want to do that for display, and not as part of a `tel:` URL for actual phone dialing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attributedString and change the font size to big enough of all asterisks